# How to hide menu items as per roles in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I have **Web.sitemap** file like this  :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home"  description=" this is the home page" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/ProjectList.aspx" title="Project List"  description="Approved projects" />
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Project Choices" description="">
            <siteMapNode url="~/StudentChoices.aspx" title="Student Project Choices"  description="" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/StaffChoices.aspx" title="Supervisor Project Choices"  description="" />
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/AllocationList.aspx" title="Project Allocation List"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Submit Proposal" description="" >
            <siteMapNode url="~/submit.aspx" title="New Proposal"  description="new proposal" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/reSubmit.aspx" title="Re-Submit Proposal" description="re submit proposal"/>
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/StaffRecords.aspx" title="Staff Records"  description="" >
            <siteMapNode url="~/addStaff.aspx" title="Add new Staff" description="" />
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/StudentRecords.aspx" title="Student Records"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Administration.aspx" title="Administration"  description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

in MasterPage i wrote following things :

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
                BackColor="#33CCFF" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Font-Overline="False"
                Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="Black" ItemWrap="True" StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                StaticSubMenuIndent="60px" Width="100%">
                <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#9999FF" ForeColor="Black" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor="#0099FF" ForeColor="Black" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#0099FF" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#0099FF" ForeColor="Black" />
            </asp:Menu>
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
            <br />
```

so, when i load site i am able to all MENU items ,

but as per roles i want to remove few items,

for this :

i wrote following things :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ManageMenuItemAsperRoles();
            }
    }
```

and in function ManageMenuItemAsperRoles();

```
public void ManageMenuItemAsperRoles()
    {
        string role = Session["Roles"].ToString();
        string AdminRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminRole"];
        string StaffRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StaffRole"];
        string StudentRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StudentRole"];
        if (role == StaffRole)
        {
            MenuItemCollection menuItems = Menu1.Items;
            MenuItem ProjectChoicesItem = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem StaffRecordsItem = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem StudentRecordsItem = new MenuItem();
            foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
            {
                if (menuItem.Text == "Project Choices")
                    ProjectChoicesItem = menuItem;
            }
            foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
            {
                if (menuItem.Text == "Staff Records")
                    StaffRecordsItem = menuItem;
            }
            foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
            {
                if (menuItem.Text == "Student Records")
                    StudentRecordsItem = menuItem;
            }
            menuItems.Remove(ProjectChoicesItem);
            menuItems.Remove(StaffRecordsItem);
            menuItems.Remove(StudentRecordsItem);
        }
    }
```

but problem is , when i put break points i found that, there is no item in : **Menu1.Items;**

and i am not able to remove few menu items,

why?

Comment: Instead of iterating over menuItems 3 times, you should do it once and check for each condition during the iteration. Your program is doing a lot of unnecessary looping there. That won't fix your problem though.

Comment: i am not  worry about the unnecessary looping, i know that stuff, but primary goal is to remove items

Answer (score 0):

No, not in Page_Load. You have to do it in MenuItemDataBound:

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    string role = Session["Roles"].ToString();
    string AdminRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminRole"];
    string StaffRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StaffRole"];
    string StudentRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StudentRole"];

    if (role == StaffRole)
    {
        if (e.Item.Text == "Project Choices" ||
            e.Item.Text == "Staff Records" ||
            e.Item.Text == "Student Records")
        {
            Menu1.Items.Remove(e.Item);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net Web does not provide properties per Menu Item to specify visibility. So it wont be possible to set specific menu items to 'appear' visible per user. But the caveat of this is that you can however just NOT create the menu item in the first place.

Eg: Do not add your menu item via the Visual Studio Designer view. Add the items that are static regardless of authentication level.

in the on Page Load Event - perform the check for authentication. If the user is authenticated, create the Menu Items you want to appear when authenticated, via the object oriented approach - utilizing their constructors and setting any needed properties. I do this in my Site.Master page: because I want the menu to behave this way for all pages.

But you can however do it per individual page if you need to.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        MenuItem m = new MenuItem("Upload");
        m.NavigateUrl = "~/Uploader/Upload.aspx";
        NavigationMenu.Items.Add(m);
    }
}
```

PS - I have posted this answer elsewhere in similar questions, but the answer remains valid for this scenario.
To further enhance this, you can analyse the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity class, to get the Username of the user, and then make menu options appear for them specifically.
You should not however rely upon the username on its own for authentication of the users role. Using a UID from a database, and assigning a non user friendly token to the user as their identity would make it more secure than a string variable that identifies their account.
But that is discussing a different topic, for now : the details above regarding the MenuItem() should suffice.